# Why composer install timeouts after 300 seconds?

Tags: symfony, timeout, composer-php

I have small project made in symfony2 when I try to build it on my server it's always fails when unzipping symfony. Build was OK and suddenly composer won't unzip symfony and I didn't change anything. I tried to build with Jenkins and also manually from bash with same result. It's not permissions problem and also internet connection on my server is OK.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
 - Installing symfony/symfony (v2.3.4)
 Downloading: 100%
[Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]
The process "unzip '/path/vendor/symfony/symfony/6116f6f3
d4125a757858954cb107e64b' -d 'vendor/composer/b2f33269' && chmod -R u+w 'vendor/composer/b2f33269'" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.
```

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Check with `composer update/install -o -vvv` whether the package is being loaded from composers' cache.

If yes, try clearing composer's cache or try adding `--cache-dir=/dev/null`.

To force downloading an archive instead of cloning sources, use the `--prefer-dist` option in combination with `--no-dev`.

Otherwise you could try raising composer's process timeout value:

```
export COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=600 # default is 300
```

Comment: well package is written into cache. see pastebin, it's too large for comment http://pastebin.com/sb7deyNc
same result with update command. Also extending time will not help I think it's 4-core machine and it's almost not working.

Comment: Using `php composer.php install --prefer-dist --no-dev` worked for me.

Comment: Works for me too. Does anyone know *why*?

Comment: Well after while I figure out why this happened and the reason was slow NFS. I don't know why, since it's on local network, but I made a switch to sshfs and it's working without problem.

Comment: A common problem is NFS shares being slow when it comes to heavy disk i/o ... i.e. cache folders are affected by this. You can work around this by moving cache folders to `/dev/shm/`. In the case of composer you could use `--cache-dir=/dev/shm/composer/cache`. Read more about it in **[this article](http://www.whitewashing.de/2013/08/19/speedup_symfony2_on_vagrant_boxes.html)** that targets performance tricks for symfony2 with vagrant nfs shares. Glad you solved your issue though. You might still consider accepting my answer as 11 upvotes + the comments clearly state it is helpful for others.

Comment: I found that I couldn't use a `cache-dir` option when running composer (1.0-dev), neither via `--cache-dir` nor `-cache-dir`.  Instead, I had to add it into my `composer.json` file: `"config": { "cache-dir": "/dev/shm/composer/cache" }`.

Comment: `export COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=600` ( defaults to 300 )

Answer (score 99):

```
composer config --global process-timeout 2000
```

Comment: or without --global if you want to set in a specific composer.json

Answer (score 93):

The easiest method is add config option to composer.json file, Add process-timeout 0, That's all. It works anywhere.

```
{
  .....
  "scripts": {
    "start": "php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public public/index.php"
  },
  "config": {
    "process-timeout":0
  }
}
```

Comment: As of composer 1.9, you can also disable process timeout on a per script basis. eg. `"start": ["Composer\\Config::disableProcessTimeout","php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public public/index.php"],`

Comment: This is what the answer from @Ali Motameni does for you, and what the comment under the answer does (by @morris4). They both actually change the corresponding composer.json file for you, altering this config value. One changes it in your global composer.json file, and the one from the comment changes it in the current project's composer.json file.

Comment: This ultimately worked for me, after trying every other suggestion here, including increasing the timeout to 2000 seconds. I wanted to add that the problematic package for me was google/apiclient-services, as mentioned in another comment, but that comment's solution did not work for me. Not only did I have to disable the process-timeout, but I had to let it run overnight! I had also closed all apps, doubled my Docker RAM and processers in .wslconfig, and restarted WSL.

Answer (score 39):

Composer itself impose a limit on how long it would allow for the remote git operation. A look at the [Composer documentation](http://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-process-timeout) confirms that the *environment variable* `COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT` governs this. The variable is set to a default value of 300 (seconds) which is apparently not enough for a large clone operation using a slow internet connection.

Raise this value using:

```
COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=2000 composer install
```

Comment: Worked for my problem. only use this command 
COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=2000 composer install

Answer (score 8):

It's an old thread but I found out the reason for time out was running a php debugger (PHPStorm was listening to xdebug connections) which caused the process timeout. When I closed the PHPStorm or disabled the xdebug extension, no time out occurred.

Comment: This was indeed the reason for my timeout, VS Code was debugging and I'd left it listening for connections...

Answer (score 8):

old thread but new problem for me. No solutions here were working when trying to install google/apiclient (it failed on google/apiclient-services) on an Ubuntu VM within a Windows 10 host.

After noticing Windows' "antimalware executable" taking up considerable CPU cycles when doing this composer install/update, I disabled "real-time protection" on the Windows 10 machine, and my composer update/install worked!!

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: It helped me! I had the exact same problem installing the google/apiclient on an Ubuntu VM running on Windows 10 via VirtualBox and this fixed the issue.

Comment: Even on Windows 11, this appears to have also helped with this issue. You can always re-enable the setting later, or let it turn back on by itself.

Comment: I have a docker in windows 10 using ubuntu, I was facing the same problem with google/apiclient and I disabled the antimalware realtime protection and it worked for me

Comment: It's brave to disable antivirus while installing foreign packages from the internet...

Comment: This helped me as well!

Comment: I thought for sure this would help me, as I am also on Ubuntu VM on Windows 11 trying to install google/apiclient-services. However, it did not work for me. What ended up working was disabling the timeout completely and letting it run overnight! Crazy. Just wanted to add my comment here since it specifically mentioned google/apiclient-services.

Answer (score 5):

Deleting composer cache worked for me.

```
rm -rf ~/.composer/cache/*
```

Answer (score 4):

The Symfony Component has process timeout set to 60 by default. That's why you get errors like this:

```
[Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]     
The process "composer update" exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds.
```

**Solution**

Set timeout to 5 minutes or more

```
$process = new Process("composer update");
$process->setTimeout(300); // 5 minutes
$process->run();
```

Comment: The snippet in the question says `exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds`. So it would either need to be higher than 300, or else the timeout isn't the problem (could be a caching issue, per @nifr and @wormhit's answers).

Answer (score 2):

### Feeling Pain: `google/apiclient` & repeated download attempts

I was having an issue with `composer` and `google/apiclient`, running in an **ubuntu** **Docker**, on a Mac host machine *(and not windows like other people)*.

**The problem: it was continuing to try download every 5 minutes**. This was not noticeable at first because there are no timestamps, even when running `composer -vvv install`. After many increments of 5-15 minutes, I painfully realized I was in a programmer's hell - waiting long periods of time between each attempt to fix said problem. Additionally, I have no real "timeout" error messaging to help figure this out.

Things I tried:

- `export COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=600 # default is 300`
- adding to the `composer.json`'s `config` section: `"process-timeout": 0`
- compression of downloads - also in config section: `"compressed": true`

Example of repeating lines:

```
Reading /root/.cache/composer/files/watson/rememberable/61967a1ee36ae90d92cb250b916ec819f141400a.zip from cache
  - Loading watson/rememberable (6.1.0) from cache
[302] https://api.github.com/repos/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/zipball/033de899257a294ca82f52fe4296dac011d01f74
Following redirect (1) https://codeload.github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/legacy.zip/033de899257a294ca82f52fe4296dac011d01f74
  - Downloading google/apiclient-services (v0.326.0)
Downloading https://api.github.com/repos/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/zipball/033de899257a294ca82f52fe4296dac011d01f74
[302] https://api.github.com/repos/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/zipball/033de899257a294ca82f52fe4296dac011d01f74
Following redirect (1) https://codeload.github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/legacy.zip/033de899257a294ca82f52fe4296dac011d01f74
  - Downloading google/apiclient-services (v0.326.0)
Downloading https://api.github.com/repos/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/zipball/033de899257a294ca82f52fe4296dac011d01f74
[302] https://api.github.com/repos/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/zipball/033de899257a294ca82f52fe4296dac011d01f74
Following redirect (1) https://codeload.github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/legacy.zip/033de899257a294ca82f52fe4296dac011d01f74
  - Downloading google/apiclient-services (v0.326.0)
Downloading https://api.github.com/repos/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/zipball/033de899257a294ca82f52fe4296dac011d01f74
```

### Fixing the problem with php.ini

When I finally realized it was `5 minutes` timeout, I started to question my `php.ini` settings.

Supported by [this article on composer's site](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#network-timeout-issues-curl-error), I discovered that I could edit the `default_socket_timeout` since it will choose which ever number is larger (default 300) or default_socket_timeout (default 60):

> It means your network is probably so slow that a request took over 300seconds to complete. This is the minimum timeout Composer will use, but you can increase it by increasing the default_socket_timeout value in your php.ini to something higher.

✔️ Here's what I set mine (`/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini`) to and it worked:

```
; Default timeout for socket based streams (seconds)
; https://php.net/default-socket-timeout
; default_socket_timeout = 60
default_socket_timeout = 3600
```

---

#### Additional Note: `compress: true` was a bad idea

I got it to download (had to set to more than 10 mins!) However, I got a new problem about zip archives - so I removed the `compress: true` from config, removed the `vendor` folder, and `composer clearcache` in hopes that it would solve the issue. It worked!

Zip archive related Error messages:

```
Executing async command (CWD): '/usr/bin/unzip' -qq

Failed to extract google/apiclient-services

End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.

The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems)
Unzip with unzip command failed, falling back to ZipArchive class
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with most of what has been suggested above, but I had the same issue and what worked for me was deleting the vendor folder and re-run `composer install`

Regards

Comment: Locally or on the server?

Comment: Wherever it is the issue is being experienced

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions worked for me running on win10 wsl ubuntu (disabling firewall, removing debuggers, clearing cache, increasing timeout, deleting vendor).
The only way that worked was deleting vendor and composer.lock from the main machine, copying composer.json to a fresh machine, install php and composer, run composer install (it should take less than 1 second to execute), then copying the vendor dir to the other machine, and run composer update.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 11, and somewhat related to an above answer, adding a folder exclusion to real-time protection can stop the "antimalware executable" from scanning the folder and causing the timeout (and saves entirely disabling "real-time protection").