# composer exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds while installing Sylius on composer GitBash

Tags: php, bash

I trying to install Sylius `composer create-project -s dev sylius/sylius` via Git bash in Windows (WAMP) and got this

```
[Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]
The process ""c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe" "app/console" assets:insta
ll "web"" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.
```

i changed phi.ini

```
realpath_cache_size = 16k
realpath_cache_ttl = 120

memory_limit = 512M //było 128M
max_input_time = 600 //60
max_execution_time = 120
```

i did `export COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=6000   ( defaults to 300 )` in MINGW32 (bash in windows) to change composer timeout like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18917919/3190476

i did this `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;` like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17466797/3190476

Comment: Composer isn't exceeding the timeout, it's actually `php app/console assets:install web` that's failing.

Comment: i have nowhere number `300` in php.ini (both php and apache directories)

Comment: Symfony sets its own default timeout. You can define your own with `--timeout` in your `app/console` commands. Either way something is funky with your assets. Clear your caches and ensure that the `web` folder is writable.

Comment: is this notation correct? `composer create-project -s dev sylius/sylius --timeout 6000`

Comment: No, your `app/console` commands. I'm telling you that `php app/console` is failing to install assets. Nothing to do with composer!

Comment: so how to do this as i have empty directory and run  `composer create-project -s dev sylius/sylius` on that empty directory. And this timeout error is result of that command.

Comment: Did you clear out your Symfony caches? `rm -rf app/cache/*`

Comment: @sjagr I can't clear Symfony caches cause I'm creating new project with new Symfony. Now, after clearing Composer cache same error occur.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

for one time solution

```
COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=2000 php composer.phar install
```

Or add to composer registry if you use it globally as I do

```
composer --global config process-timeout 2000
```

I found the solution here: http://www.papayasoft.com/2013/08/22/composer-process-timeout-when-fetching-large-repositories/

Answer (score 16):

Add config option in composer.json file
It is best solution for your projects
only add process-timeout key and value to 0

```
{....
"config": {
    "process-timeout":0
  }
}
```

Comment: disable for composer script https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#process-timeout