# Deploying a Laravel App on Azure

Tags: php, azure, laravel-5.1, web-deployment

I am having a problem deploying my laravel 5.1 app, i don't have a customized deployment script... I already added the web.config file as specified in this [tutorial](http://blog.qbotx.com/basic-laravel-5-on-microsoft-azure-part-1/)

I have already installed composer. I already increased the composer timeout to 2000. The problem is that until now the deployment is still loading and it has been hours passed.

I'm using azure web app service.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't take that long, can you disable the timeout, replace the "`php artisan Optimize`" with the "`composer dump-autoload -o`" in the composer.json - at post-install-cmd step
if it still doesn't work, we should check the logs and see what's happening.

Comment: It is currently at this stage: Generating optimized class loader...

 Other people are also having the same problem... check on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34928898/php-artisan-optimize-times-out-only-on-composer-install)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround currently for deploying Laravel 5 applications to Azure Web Apps.

I removed the following commands under `"post-install-cmd"` scripts closure:

```
"php artisan clear-compiled",
"php artisan optimize"
```

Then Leverage Git to deploy to Azure Web App. For now, it will not throw the timeout processing exception when deploying.

Then install the Visual Studio online extension of your site the same as installing composer:
[image]

Click brower button to login the VSO which can modify and run console commands of your application:
[image]

click the "console" button open the cmdlet, run those command:

```
"php artisan clear-compiled",
"php artisan optimize"
```

[image]

And rest steps, you still can follow this [tutorial](http://blog.qbotx.com/basic-laravel-5-on-microsoft-azure-part-1/)

Comment: If  you remove the commands under the `post-install-cmd` in composer.json file, it shouldn't run the these commands which may raise this issue. You still get the issue when composer installing denpendencies?