# Setup a PHP/Laravel 5 project with Bootstrap SB Admin 2 in Microsoft Azure

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, azure

My plan is to make a lavarel project using bootstrap sb admin 2 template. In order to tweak azure, I used this [tutorial](http://blog.bobbyallen.me/2015/06/26/configuring-and-hosting-laravel-5-x-applications-on-windows-azure/).

Instead of bitbucket I used Github.

In the azure web app, I installed the composer extension. 
From the Kudu console I installed bower and gulp

```
D:\home\site>npm install bower
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\home\site\package.json' 
npm WARN site No description 
npm WARN site No repository field. 
npm WARN site No README data npm WARN site No license field.


D:\home\site>npm install gulp
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
```

I prepared the Laravel framework with [SB admin](http://startlaravel.com/themes/sb-admin-laravel-5/) in localhost and then I tried to push everything in github. The result was a failure because azure cannot sychronize with Github. I think that there is a problem with either bower or gulp but I don't know how to fix it. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

The result:
[image]

```
Command: D:\home\SiteExtensions\ComposerExtension\Hooks\deploy.cmd

Install Dependencies with Composer

Loading composer repositories with package information

Installing dependencies from lock file

Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.

Nothing to install or update

Generating optimized autoload files

> php artisan clear-compiled

> php artisan optimize

Generating optimized class loader



  [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]           

  The process "php artisan optimize" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.  



An error has occurred during web site deployment.

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...

Loading composer repositories with package information\r\nInstalling dependencies from lock file\r\nWarning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.\r\nNothing to install or update\r\nGenerating optimized autoload files\r\n> php artisan clear-compiled\r\n> php artisan optimize\r\n\r\n                                                                           \r\n  [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]           \r\n  The process "php artisan optimize" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.  \r\n                                                                           \r\n\r\ninstall [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...\r\nC:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\55.50526.2249\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd D:\home\SiteExtensions\ComposerExtension\Hooks\deploy.cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the commands:

```
"php artisan clear-compiled",
"php artisan optimize"
```

under `"post-install-cmd"` scripts closure in `composer.json` file. Then run these commands via VSO or KUDU console site after deployment.

Here is a same issue with on SO, [Deploying a Laravel App on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029959/deploying-a-laravel-app-on-azure/35054474#35054474). And you can refer to this answer as a workaround to solve your issue.