# When PHP built in server crashes, the port is still in use

Tags: php, composer-php, php-builtin-server

I'm using PHP built in server like so:

```
$ composer serve
> php -S localhost:8000 -t public/
```

But it timed out..?

```
[Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]                     
  The process "php -S localhost:8080 -t public/" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.
```

So, I tried to start it up again:

```
$ composer serve
> php -S localhost:8000 -t public/
[Thu May 26 21:31:51 2016] Failed to listen on localhost:8000 (reason: Address already in use)
Script php -S localhost:8000 -t public/ handling the serve event returned with error code 1
```

Why is the same port that the server was running on prior to timing out still in use? Can I stop all instances of PHP built in server?

If it matters, below is my composer.json file:

```
{
    .
    .
    .
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "php -S localhost:8000 -t public/"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that composer has a default timeout after 300 seconds.

Composer ships with the [composer-script process-timeout static helper](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#process-timeout) to disable it, just add it on top of your script:

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "serve": [
            "Composer\\Config::disableProcessTimeout",
            "@php -S localhost:8000 -t public"
        ]
    }
}
```

To test without changing the script, executing the command you can use `--timeout=0`, this disables the timeout. In your example the command would look like `composer run-script --timeout=0 serve` or prefix with the environment parameter like `COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=0 composer serve`.

More information is also available in [Why composer install timeouts after 300 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18917768/367456) on site.

Comment: I see, thanks. Might just go back to typing out the full "php -S ..." then as I only preferred the convenience of just typing "composer serve" :) I take it there is no means to put the --timeout value into the composer.json file?

Answer (score 5):

you can set the process timeout in your `composer.json` file like this :

```
  {
    ...
    "scripts": {
      "start": "php -S 127.0.0.1:80 .router.php -t public"
    },
    "config": {
      "process-timeout": 0
    }
  }
```

and start the web server like this :

`$ composer start`

Answer (score 0):

You can disabled composers timeout.

```json
"scripts": {
    "serve": [
      "Composer\\Config::disableProcessTimeout",
      "@php -S 127.0.0.1:80 -t public"
    ]
}
```