# Symfony cache:clear timeout - Exceeded 300 seconds

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony4

I'm having an issue with my Symfony 4.3 project and composer. Whenever I try to install, remove, or do anything, it just stops on the "Executing script cache:clear" part and sits there until the timeout hits. I've tried increasing the timeout to something crazy like 2000 and did not help, it would just sit there.

Anyone know how to fix this?

```
λ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
ocramius/package-versions: Generating version class...
ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
Executing script cache:clear

  [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]
  The process ""C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.3.9\php.exe" "--php-ini=C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.3.9\php.ini" "./bin/
  console" --ansi cache:clear" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

I've tried manually deleting the var/cache contents, but it doesn't help. I have been looking all over the googles for an answer, and stackoverflow.

Comment: X-Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18917768/367456

Answer (score 1):

I found my issue. In my twig.yaml I had the node_modules folder path in there. I forgot to remove it when I was testing a css file and when the cache:clear does the warmup, it literally was going through a 100k of folders and files. Which explains why 300 seconds isn't enough time, and even if I had it set to 2000 seconds I bet it still would have ran out of time.

Lesson Learn: Be careful of your twig configurations!!!

Answer (score 1):

I hope that this can be help, try in this way

> composer install --prefer-dist --no-scripts -vvv