# Install of tcg/voyager failed

Tags: php, laravel, git, composer-php

In fresh new install of a laravel project, I started to install VOYAGER in my project as the following steps:

- composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel badrhb "6.*"
- composer require tcg/voyager
  and here I got an error as follow:

```
....
.....
...
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Syncing tcg/voyager (1.x-dev aaee6ab) into cache
  - Installing tcg/voyager (1.x-dev aaee6ab): Cloning aaee6abbdd
    Install of tcg/voyager failed

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.


  [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]
  The process "git clone --no-checkout "https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager.git" "C:\wamp64\www\badrhb\vendo
  r\tcg\voyager" && cd /D "C:\wamp64\www\badrhb\vendor\tcg\voyager" && git remote add composer "https://github.com/th
  e-control-group/voyager.git" && git fetch composer && git remote set-url origin "https://github.com/the-control-gro
  up/voyager.git" && git remote set-url composer "https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager.git"" exceeded the tim
  eout of 300 seconds.


require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Some answers said that I don't have the git command on your system path.
So what is the solution for this?

Comment: extend the time-limit probably. see composer docs about the time-limit or earlier contributions like https://stackoverflow.com/q/18917768/367456 (it has more good suggestions, too)

Comment: and `composer diagnose` is a good self-check for e.g. if git is there etc. - then you know more already regarding your own box/system/environment.

Comment: Do you have git installed?

Comment: @hakre yes it is , the problem was time-limit, so I changed it with export `COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=1600`  and it resolved the problem.